# ファイルシステムext4とxfsのIOPSの差が10倍

Tags: linux, centos, aws, filesystems

下の`IOPS=33.9k`はxfsでやると3354と表示されました。何度やっても10倍くらいの差になります。

ファイルシステムでそこまで変わるとは思えないので、フォーマットのやり方に問題があるのかもしれませんがこちらのとおりやってます。
https://qiita.com/shiru/items/c765accff6d3c5f8ea34

ただ、マウント時にxfsだと下のオプションが使えないのでそのまま`mount /dev/md0`とやっていますが、これが問題でしょうか？

XFS
mount /dev/md0 /media/ephemeral0

EXT4
    mount -o rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered /dev/md0 /media/ephemeral0

> fio -name=random-write       -ioengine=libaio       -rw=randrw       -rwmixread=0       -bs=16k       -numjobs=16       -iodepth=16       -size=100m       -direct=1       -directory=/media/ephemeral0       -group_reporting
>   random-write: (g=0): rw=randrw, bs=(R) 16.0KiB-16.0KiB, (W) 16.0KiB-16.0KiB, (T) 16.0KiB-16.0KiB, ioengine=libaio, iodepth=16
>   ...
>   fio-3.3
>   Starting 16 processes
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   random-write: Laying out IO file (1 file / 100MiB)
>   Jobs: 1 (f=1): [w(1),_(15)][100.0%][r=0KiB/s,w=502MiB/s][r=0,w=32.1k IOPS][eta 00m:00s]
>   random-write: (groupid=0, jobs=16): err= 0: pid=6855: Thu Jan  4 08:26:29 2018
>     write: IOPS=33.9k, BW=529MiB/s (555MB/s)(1600MiB/3022msec)
>       slat (usec): min=3, max=27676, avg=253.30, stdev=1452.90
>       clat (usec): min=89, max=64093, avg=7102.46, stdev=5838.76
>        lat (usec): min=141, max=64104, avg=7356.88, stdev=6093.65
>       clat percentiles (usec):
>        |  1.00th=[  157],  5.00th=[  219], 10.00th=[  318], 20.00th=[  750],
>        | 30.00th=[ 3359], 40.00th=[ 5276], 50.00th=[ 6456], 60.00th=[ 7898],
>        | 70.00th=[ 9372], 80.00th=[11469], 90.00th=[15008], 95.00th=[17433],
>        | 99.00th=[23200], 99.50th=[27132], 99.90th=[43779], 99.95th=[47973],
>        | 99.99th=[54789]
>      bw (  KiB/s): min=22176, max=52544, per=6.54%, avg=35470.31, stdev=4276.22, samples=81
>      iops        : min= 1386, max= 3284, avg=2216.56, stdev=267.30, samples=81
>     lat (usec)   : 100=0.01%, 250=6.73%, 500=9.79%, 750=3.48%, 1000=1.71%
>     lat (msec)   : 2=3.19%, 4=7.53%, 10=41.29%, 20=24.05%, 50=2.18%
>     lat (msec)   : 100=0.04%
>     cpu          : usr=1.68%, sys=5.76%, ctx=20890, majf=0, minf=514
>     IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=0.1%, 16=99.8%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
>        submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
>        complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.1%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
>        issued rwt: total=0,102400,0, short=0,0,0, dropped=0,0,0
>        latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=16

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=529MiB/s (555MB/s), 529MiB/s-529MiB/s (555MB/s-555MB/s), io=1600MiB (1678MB), run=3022-3022msec

Disk stats (read/write):
    md0: ios=0/96376, merge=0/0, ticks=0/0, in_queue=0, util=0.00%, aggrios=0/49418, aggrmerge=0/1797, aggrticks=0/229064, aggrin_queue=229245, aggrutil=82.68%
  xvdb: ios=0/50290, merge=0/926, ticks=0/307177, in_queue=307422, util=81.91%
  xvdc: ios=0/48546, merge=0/2669, ticks=0/150951, in_queue=151069, util=82.68%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ファイルシステムの**デフォルトチューニング**の性能比較であれば結果の通りでしょう。

**ファイルシステム自体**の性能比較であれば、適切にチューニングを行わなければ意味がありません。わかりやすい値としてブロックサイズを適切に設定する必要があります。EXT4は[tune2fs](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/e2fsprogs/man8/tune2fs.8.html)、XFSは[xfs_info](https://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_info)で各パラメーターを確認できます。ベンチマークが`-bs=16k`とのことなので、どちらのファイルシステムも16kにすべきでしょう。

なお、XFSはジャーナルログを別デバイスに設定できます。パフォーマンスを求めるのであれば別ディスク（≠別パーティション）に設定すべきでしょう。